# ServiceStack Licensing Model

Tags: servicestack

I've purchased a license in the past. Now that it's expired, do I have to purchase a new license to continue using ServiceStack? Will there be any rate limits or anything else if I don't purchase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The license you purchased is perpetual. That means you can use the last updated version of the software before your license expiration date without having to renew. If you renew you will get access to the latest updates.

See https://servicestack.net/pricing
[image]